# ASP.Net MVC: posting/binding/saving hidden field to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new in ASP.Net MVC.
I have a model that has following fields:
Event Name, Start time, End time, owner.

Now in the view I have similar to this (to render and post updated data through form):

```
<tbody>
    @if (Model.Events != null)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < Model.Events.Count; i++)
       {
        <tr class="event-record">
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Events[i].EventName, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Events[i].StartTime, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Events[i].EndTime, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
        </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Now my view doesn't have any input text field for owner and I intent to fill that owner field by javascript and post that information along with other fields that are visible.

[UPDATE]Here is my HTTP Post action:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "EventSaveExit")]
public ActionResult EventSaveExit(MasterEvent masterEvents)
{
    CreateUpdateEvent(masterEvents);
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

How can I achieve that result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your HttpPost action looks like ?

Comment: I have update my question with the HTTP post action

Comment: You have a loop inside your view, but you are saving only one event ? What are you trying to do  ? Saving one event or multiple events ?

Comment: Actually my model is a MasterEvent that can have multiple child events. Child events are stored in a list. whie rendering child events I am looping through that list. But in action method I am getting the MasterEvent. 

I have modified the actionMethod for you to understand clearly. Thanks.

Comment: On what event you want to set the value using javascript ? You want to set to all the records ?

Comment: Yes. I can get the user name from my global variable. So whoever adding that event, his user name should be saved in the owner field, for each event.

Comment: You should not do that in client side. See my answer.

Comment: In my case the hidden fields were outside of the form. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a hidden field for Owner property. You can use the `HiddenFor` helper method to create the hidden field.

```
<tr class="event-record">
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Events[i].EventName, new {@class = "form-control"})
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Events[i].Owner, new {@class = "form-control ownerItem"})
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can use javascript to set the value of your hidden field. The below code use jQuery and will set all owner hidden field's value to "Scott" on the document ready event.

```
$(function(){
    //set to all input element's with ownerItem css class
    $("input.ownerItem").val("Scott");
});
```

**Never trust client side data**

If you are trying to save the current username as the Owner property value for each record, you should not do that in client side because anyone can open your site and using browser dev tools, update the value of the hidden field to any name and save the record. You should be doing that in server side.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EventSaveExit(MasterEvent masterEvents)
{
   foreach (var eventVm in masterEvents.Events)
   {
      eventVm.Owner = "Set the value here";
   }
   // now continue saving
   CreateUpdateEvent(masterEvents);
   return Redirect("/");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Events[i].Owner)
```

That should give you a hidden text box, bound to the Owner property.

It basically renders to an `<input type="hidden" ...` element